# Dynamic Linq to evaluate a JObject

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I'm using the [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamic-linq.net/) library. There are some expressions which are not evaluating, and I believe it's because the object gets deserialized to a JObject.

I have the following test which is failing:

```
    [Test]
    public void Should_Evaluate_A_JObject()
    {
        // given
        var jObject = new JObject
        {
            ["Role"] = "admin"
        };

        // when
        "Role == admin".Evaluates(jObject).Should().BeTrue();
    }
```

The `Evaluates` code looks like this:

```
public static bool Evaluates<T>(this string expression, T value)
{
    var list = new List<T>() { value };
    return list.AsQueryable().Any(expression);
}
```

Anybody got any ideas on how I can further my investigation? Or know how I can write the expression such it'll evaluate a `JObject`.

Answer (score 0):

In [WireMock.Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) I had more or less the same issue.

I wanted to convert a `JObject` to a dynamic linq `Select` query so that I could do some querying.

The code is defined here [WireMock.Net/Util/JsonUtils.cs](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/blob/master/src/WireMock.Net/Util/JsonUtils.cs#L98).

And this can be used like:

```cs
[Fact]
public void JsonUtils_GenerateDynamicLinqStatement_JObject2()
{
    // Assign
    var j = new JObject
    {
        {"U", new JValue(new Uri("http://localhost:80/abc?a=5"))},
        {"N", new JValue((object) null)},
        {"G", new JValue(Guid.NewGuid())},
        {"Flt", new JValue(10.0f)},
        {"Dbl", new JValue(Math.PI)},
        {"Check", new JValue(true)},
        {
            "Child", new JObject
            {
                {"ChildId", new JValue(4)},
                {"ChildDateTime", new JValue(new DateTime(2018, 2, 17))},
                {"TS", new JValue(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(999))}
            }
        },
        {"I", new JValue(9)},
        {"L", new JValue(long.MaxValue)},
        {"Name", new JValue("Test")}
    };

    // Act
    string line = JsonUtils.GenerateDynamicLinqStatement(j);

    // Assert 1
    line.Should().Be("new (Uri(U) as U, null as N, Guid(G) as G, double(Flt) as Flt, double(Dbl) as Dbl, bool(Check) as Check, new (long(Child.ChildId) as ChildId, DateTime(Child.ChildDateTime) as ChildDateTime, TimeSpan(Child.TS) as TS) as Child, long(I) as I, long(L) as L, string(Name) as Name)");

    // Assert 2
    var queryable = new[] { j }.AsQueryable().Select(line);
    bool result = queryable.Any("I > 1 && L > 1");
    result.Should().BeTrue();
}
```

I hope this solution gives you some hints and point in the right direction.